# How to get the URL as shown in browser's address bar in JAVA?

Tags: java, url, browser

I searched for this many times and their is no clear answer for it on the Internet : can I get the URL exactly as it appears in web browser's address bar in Java and, if yes, how ?

I mean the exact address : for me now, it would be "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", or "https: //stackoverflow.com/questions/54790941/how-to-get-the-url-as-shown-in-browsers-address-bar-in-java" (without the space between : and /) for this post.

I know that I can't have the "#..." because this is not transmitted by the browser, so this should be an exception.

To make this simple, I would like to have the exact thing has the "window.location.href" in JavaScript.

Thanks !

Comment: can you describe a little bit more, because i am not following you

Comment: @BryanAcuñaNúñez : What do you don't get, please ? I will edit my question to be more clear, but I really don't see what is unclear.